# IF Statement with Network days

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, formulas

I'm trying to write a formula using an IF and Networkdays function.  I basically want this formula to look in column J3 and see if there is a date.  If there is a date the it should return the number of work days between the completion date and the discovery date.

If J3 (completion date) is blank, which means it hasn't benn completed, then I just want it to return blank

[image: Crop of pic]

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you're already using as a formula?

Comment: Yes no problem.  =NETWORKDAYS(A3,J3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
=IF(J3 = "", "", NETWORKDAYS(A3, J3))
```

You already had 50% of the formula.

The `IF` statement will check whether or not `J3` is blank (i.e. ""). If that is true, it will return a blank value. If it's false meaning that there is something in there, it will return your formula.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: What if I had a similar formula lets say J3-L3 and I want the formula to return a blank if J3 is empty.  Of course if it's not empty it will go ahead and proceed to return the anwer of the formula

Comment: Same idea. You have `=IF(statement, TRUE, FALSE)`. The statement checks to see whether J3 is blank, if true it does whatever is in the true section (in this case return ""), and if its not blank whatever is in the false section. So, all you would need to do would be to alter the false portion with your new formula.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula that I use:

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS($G7,$H7)>0, NETWORKDAYS($G7,$H7),"-")
```